# Lisp - is not of the expected type NUMBER

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am receiving the following error in my Lisp code:

```
value (PROBLEM1 (+ N 1)) is not of the expected type NUMBER.
```

The intent of the code is to sum all numbers up to 1000 that are divisible by 3 or 5.

```
(defun problem1 (n)
  (if (< n 1000)
      (if (or (= 0 (mod n 3)) (= 0 (mod n 5))) 
      (apply '+ '(n (problem1 (+ n 1)))) 
      (apply '+ '(0 (problem1 (+ n 1)))))
   0))
```

I realize that the error is probably because problem1 is returning a list - but when I trace the values in my head the function should work correctly.  Therefore, can someone explain to me if I am misusing (or missing) an apostrophe?

Comment: Sorry, no real help, but I'm learning lisp (clojure), and when I get stuck with stuff like this I just begin deconstructing things in the repl until I figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: I believe the problem is that in the final recursive call I'll have something like: `(apply '+ (3 (3))`... but I'm not sure how to resolve that list.

Comment: Just expanding on my answer, but problem1 does not return a list. It either returns 0 (if the condition of the outermost `if` is `nil`), or the result of applying `+` to a list, which can never be a list.

Comment: There's no reason to use APPLY here to begin with. Just call +.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than missing a `'`, you have too many. When you write

```
(apply '+ '(n (problem1 (+ n 1))))
```

You are trying to apply `+` to a list containing the symbol `n` and the unevaluated list `(problem1 (+ n 1))`. This is because you have quoted the argument list, and `'` prevents evaluation. What you actually want is to use `list`, e.g.

```
(apply '+ (list n (problem1 (1+ n))))
```

Comment: Or just `(+ n (problem (1+ n)))`, I don't quite see the need for apply here.